# Clean way to respect DRY for conditions

Tags: typescript, algorithm, coding-style, dry

I've got this piece of code in typescript (although the language doesn't really matter):

```js
let name = '', parentId = '';
if (obj instanceof Service) {
    name = obj.name;
} else if (obj instanceof Method) {
    name = obj.name;
    parentId = this.generateUUID(obj._parentService);
} else if (obj instanceof Argument) {
    name = obj.name;
    parentId = this.generateUUID(obj._parentMethod);
}
```

I could do the same thing with a case statement, but it wouldn't change the problem: I have a repetition of `name = obj.name;` 3 times

So I could change the code to something like:

```js
let name = '', parentId = '';

if(obj instanceof Service || obj instanceof Method || obj instanceof Argument)
    name = obj.name;

if (obj instanceof Method) {
    parentId = this.generateUUID(obj._parentService);
} else if (obj instanceof Argument) {
    parentId = this.generateUUID(obj._parentMethod);
}
```

But then I have a condition repetition that I don't really like..

Is there a way to achieve this without repetition, and with good readability?

---

Here is a minimal reproductible example of my problem:

```js
class A {name:string=''}
class B {name:string=''; parentA: A = new A()}
class C {name:string=''; parentB: B = new B()}

function hash(s: string): string{
  return '' + s.split("").reduce(function(a,b){a=((a<<5)-a)+b.charCodeAt(0);return a&a},0);              
}

function generateUUID(obj: A | B | C) {
    let name = '', parentId = '';

    if (obj instanceof A) {
        name = obj.name;
    } else if (obj instanceof B) {
        name = obj.name;
        parentId = generateUUID(obj.parentA);
    } else if (obj instanceof C) {
        name = obj.name;
        parentId = generateUUID(obj.parentB);
    }

    return hash(parentId+name);
}

const a = new A();
a.name = 'a';

const b = new B();
b.name = 'b';
b.parentA = a;

const c = new C();
c.name = 'c';
c.parentB = b;


console.log(
    generateUUID(c)
);
```

Comment: Could you edit the code into a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) where the only issue present is the repetition (so no undeclared names)?  That will increase your chances of getting a suggestion that actually works.  In TypeScript, control flow analysis limitations make it difficult to refactor type checks like this in a way that doesn't yield compiler errors.  I'd need a more complete (yet hopefully minimal) example to show that happening though.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to avoid all duplication all the time. DRY, as a principle is all about getting rid of unnecessary duplications, but does not restrict you to a situation where you cannot repeat yourself when necessary. So, keeping self-repetition to a reasonable minimum should be a compromise. I would suggest the following:

```
if(obj instanceof Service || obj instanceof Method || obj instanceof Argument) {
    name = obj.name;
    if (obj.instanceof Method) {
        parentId = this.generateUUID(obj._parentService);
    } else if (obj instanceof Argument) {
        parentId = this.generateUUID(obj._parentMethod);
    }
}
```

You can enhance this further by implementing a base class/interface, ensuring that `obj` is such an instance and implementing `generateUUID` for it as well as for all the classes which extend it, so you will not need the inner conditionals at usage-level.

Comment: Note that your `else` clause will trigger if `obj instanceof Service` which does not seem to match the original code example

Comment: @jcalz thanks for pointing that out, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already use classes it may be reasonable to put the `generateUUID` into them.

```
function hash(s: string): string {
  return "" + s.split("").reduce((a, b) => {
    a = ((a << 5) - a) + b.charCodeAt(0);
    return a & a;
  }, 0);
}

class A {
  name: string = "";

  generateUUID() {
    return hash(this.name);
  }
}

class B {
  name: string = "";
  parentA: A = new A();

  generateUUID() {
    return hash(this.parentA.generateUUID + this.name);
  }
}

class C {
  name: string = "";
  parentB: B = new B();

  generateUUID() {
    return hash(this.parentB.generateUUID + this.name);
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.name = "a";

const b = new B();
b.name = "b";
b.parentA = a;

const c = new C();
c.name = "c";
c.parentB = b;

console.log(
  c.generateUUID()
);
```